# Configuring Spring Security (two-way SSL) to not require authentication only on CORS preflight OPTIONS requests

Tags: java, firefox, spring-security, cors

I've been on a witch hunt of trying to figure out why cross-origin requests fail only in Firefox.  Turns out Firefox does not send SSL/TLS credentials on cross-origin XHRs, which apparently is defined by the [W3 CORS Spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-preflight-fetch).  I was able to *mostly* resolve this by adding a `withCredentials: true` to my XHR instances in my client code (it works for GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, etc.).

However, Firefox still refuses to add credentials to pre-flight OPTIONS requests despite me explicitly telling it to in the XHR.  Unless there is somehow a way to do this in client code, I am left with configuring my server to allow un-authenticated OPTIONS requests (which in a 2-way SSL configuration seems insane to me).  Are there security risks here?

Our server is a Spring Boot project that uses Spring Security, and is configured for 2-way SSL using X509 security certificates.  I will provide all relative code to give you an idea of how the application is configured.

Main class:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class OurApp extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    OurUserDetailsService ourUserDetailsService;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(OurApp.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
      web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // X509Configurer<HttpSecurity> x509Configurer = http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().x509();

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll().
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .x509().subjectPrincipalRegex("(.*)").authenticationUserDetailsService(ourUserDetailsService)
            .and()
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Configuration class that has CORS setup:

```
@Configuration
public class OurConfig {
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://client-origin"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "HEAD"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Content-Type", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With", "requestId", "Correlation-Id"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public IgnoredRequestCustomizer optionsIgnoredRequestsCustomizer() {
      return configurer -> {
        List<RequestMatcher> matchers = new ArrayList<>();
        matchers.add(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**", "OPTIONS"));
        configurer.requestMatchers(new OrRequestMatcher(matchers));
      };
    }
}
```

This WORKS on all GET requests, and when I manually perform the requests in browser for the other verbs -- except for OPTIONS.  The preflight request continues to fail during the TLS handshake and is aborted by Firefox.  I'm confused, is it even possible to send an un-authenticated (credential-less) request over (two-way SSL) HTTPS?

How do I configure spring security or spring boot to allow unauthenticated OPTIONS requests with a two-way SSL (over HTTPS) enabled configuration?

Comment: Chrome does it--It adds credentials to the preflight OPTIONS.  Isn't an un-authenticated request in a 2-way SSL configuration presenting a security risk?

Comment: Right, I understand Firefox is simply following the spec.  I would propose the spec allow for optional credentials if requested by the server.  But I've accepted that it won't (at least for now), and can't seem to get Spring to allow unauthenticated OPTIONS.

Comment: Right, it probably is the server.  I assume the server expects a client certificate in the TLS handshake prior to the OPTIONS being sent.  Firefox doesn't send one, TLS handshake fails, and Firefox aborts the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preflight request should exclude credentials, see [CORS specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0):

> **7.1.5 Cross-Origin Request with Preflight**
>
> To protect resources against cross-origin requests that could not originate from certain user agents before this specification existed a preflight request is made to ensure that the resource is aware of this specification. The result of this request is stored in a preflight result cache.
>
> The steps below describe what user agents must do for a **cross-origin request with preflight**. This is a request to a non same-origin URL that first needs to be authorized using either a preflight result cache entry or a preflight request.
>
> [...]
>
> - Exclude user credentials.

To handle a preflight request without credentials (SSL client certificate), you have to change the SSL configuration of your server.

For example, see [Spring Boot Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html):

> ```
> server.ssl.client-auth= # Whether client authentication is wanted ("want") or needed ("need"). Requires a trust store.
> ```